# I Am Generating listener Error In Console

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
[1676877376.906][WARNING]: virtual void DevToolsClientImpl::AddListener(DevToolsEventListener *) subscribing a listener to the already connected DevToolsClient. Connection notification will not arrive.
```

I Have this Warning Error in my console while running Selenium Scripts, Does Anyone came across this and knows how to fix it, Thank you

Comment: possibly related to: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=4330

Comment: @MarcGravell Thank you very much that was very informative